# SSRS 2005 Show Point Labels on Start and End of Line Chart

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I'm working in SSRS and I've a Line Chart. Currently I've enabled the Point Labels in my Line Chart, which shows as [image]

I want to show only the point label at start and end of each line, and hide all the labels between the start and end of line. (All numbers in Red box must be hidden or not shown)

Any Help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Expression on the Data

```
=IIF(Cstr(Format(Fields!Date.Value,"dd-MMM"))="01-Oct" or Cstr(Format(Fields!Date.Value,"dd-MMM"))="06-Oct",True,False)
```

[image]
[image: Show Start and End Data label - SSRS]

[image]

Comment: How can I select the point label from the line graph, so far I'm not able to select the data point where I can select a number, and add expression

Comment: in design mode you have to select any data label > for that data label change the "visible" property with above expression.

Comment: I selected the data field, but I can't see the Visible property in property window, although I can see Visibility property. Can you please guide me how to reach at that ?